# Inserto into ... select

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-insert

I want to insert values in column of my first table "p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate ", and these values must have the same identifier (subs_id=subs_id), but my request inserts nulls here my request and the result that I get

```
INSERT INTO p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate (activationDate) 

SELECT   b.activation_date
FROM P_EDW_BO_UNIVERSE.DW_SUBNOS  b
WHERE p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate.subs_id=b.subs_id
```

result

```
survey          subno   subs_id     activationdate
date
NULL            NULL    NULL        28/03/2013
NULL            NULL    NULL        14/09/2017
NULL            NULL    NULL        11/02/2006
NULL            NULL    NULL        07/02/2007
NULL            NULL    NULL        20/04/2011
01/07/2015  770611368   60 584 365  NULL
01/07/2015  772682168   3 541 647   NULL
01/07/2015  770827778   6 616   NULL
01/07/2015  774614365   34 444 141  NULL
01/07/2015  796997578   73 457 413  NULL
```

i want to get result like this

```
01/07/2015  770611368   60 584 365  07/02/2007
01/07/2015  772682168   3 541 647   20/04/2011
```

Comment: do you want to use `UPDATE`?

Comment: I dont understand anything to your question. Please rephrase this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to UPDATE existing data:

```
UPDATE p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate
FROM 
 ( SELECT subs_id, activation_date
   FROM P_EDW_BO_UNIVERSE.DW_SUBNOS
 ) AS b
SET activationDate = src.activationDate
WHERE p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate.subs_id=b.subs_id
```

Comment: UPDATE p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate 
FROM 
 ( SELECT subs_id, activation_date
   FROM P_EDW_BO_UNIVERSE.DW_SUBNOS
 ) AS b
SET activationDate = b.activation_date
WHERE p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate.subs_id=b.subs_id

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are selecting only column `b.activation_date`  and specifying the column `(activationDate)` name and inserting into that column only.

You need to specify the column names that you want to insert in insert and select them. So you can change your query to something like:

```
INSERT INTO p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate (survey,subno,subs_id,activationdate) 

SELECT   b.survey,b.subno,b.subs_id,b.activation_date
FROM P_EDW_BO_UNIVERSE.DW_SUBNOS  b
WHERE p_edw_tmp.TK_NPS_subdate.subs_id=b.subs_id
```